# How to loop over a sliding window of data with lapply?

Tags: r

How can I use `lapply()` to "loop" over a multi-column dataset and apply a function? Normally, I would use `rollapply()`, but for reasons that aren't worth going into the analytics in this case only works with `lapply()`. I know how to run a function over an expanding window. But how can `lapply()` be used with a sliding window? For example, here's a toy example for manually changing the range works with a function I'll call `my_fun` for a multi-column dataset (`dat1`):

```
set.seed(78)
dat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1000), ncol = 20, nrow = 50))

my_fun <-function(x) {
  a <-apply(x,1,mean)
  }

test.1 <-my_fun(dat1[1:10])
test.2 <-my_fun(dat1[2:11])
test.3 <-my_fun(dat1[3:12])
```

Using lapply() for an expanding window works too, i.e., for ranges 1:10, 1:11, 1:12:

```
test.a <-lapply(seq(10, 12), function(x) my_fun(dat1[1:x]))
```

My question: is there any way to use lapply to replicate the sliding window analysis via the 3 manual examples above? I've tried several possibilities, using rep() and replicate(), for example, but so far no success. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please review [mcve] and provide a specific function for `my_fun` and value for `dat` that captures the essence of the problem.

Comment: edited with sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test.a <-lapply(seq(1, 3), function(x) my_fun(dat1[x:(x+9)]))
```

Comment: Eric, this is essentially the solution I'm looking for -- thanks. Now that you've provided an answer, it's obvious. Apparently I suffered a bit of brain-lock here. As a side note, G. Grothendieck's code works too, but not for this specific case, which is due to the somewhat unique function I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it can be done with `rollapply` like this:

```
library(zoo)

res <- t(rollapply(t(dat1), 10, function(x) my_fun(t(x)), by.column = FALSE))

# verify that res[, i] equals test.i for i = 1,2,3
all.equal(res[, 1], test.1)
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(res[, 2], test.2)
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(res[, 3], test.3)
## [1] TRUE
```